# Pytorch geometric - Is the function of agg='add' equal to matmul(adjacency_matrix, feature_matrix)?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

i have a question concerning the following code. In particular in **(1)** it is specidied:

```
__init__(aggr='add')
```

while in **(2)** i do not have aggr='add' as in **(1)**, but a multiplication between the adjacency matrix (edge_index) and the nodes (x_j):

```
matmul(edge_index, x_j)
```

is it correct to say that they are the same and produce the same results ?

**code (1)**

```
import torch
from torch.nn import Linear, Parameter
from torch_geometric.nn import MessagePassing
from torch_geometric.utils import add_self_loops, degree

class GCNConv(MessagePassing):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super().__init__(aggr='add') 
        self.reset_parameters()

    def reset_parameters(self):
        self.lin.reset_parameters()
        

    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        # x has shape [N, in_channels]
        # edge_index has shape [2, E]

        # Step 1: Add self-loops to the adjacency matrix.
        edge_index, _ = add_self_loops(edge_index, num_nodes=x.size(0))

        # Step 4-5: Start propagating messages.
        out = self.propagate(edge_index, x=x)

        return out

    def message(self, x_j):
        return x_j
```

**code (2)**

```
import torch
from torch.nn import Linear, Parameter
from torch_geometric.nn import MessagePassing
from torch_geometric.utils import add_self_loops, degree

class GCNConv(MessagePassing):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super().__init__() 
        self.reset_parameters()

    def reset_parameters(self):
        self.lin.reset_parameters()


    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        # x has shape [N, in_channels]
        # edge_index has shape [2, E]

        edge_index, _ = add_self_loops(edge_index, num_nodes=x.size(0))

        out = self.propagate(edge_index, x=x)

        return out

    def message_and_aggregate(self, edge_index, x_j):
        return matmul(edge_index, x_j)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you described (in fact, there are some errors in your code, the code may not be able to run successfully), code 1 just adds the features of neighbor nodes and itself (there is a self-loop) to get the updated features, code 2 is Multiply the features (including its own features) by the adjacency matrix, which also adds the features of the neighbor nodes (the corresponding position of the matrix is 1). Therefore, there is essentially no difference between the two.